# How to Get ImageView Bring to front on touch event of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have two `ImageView` in two different layouts, the One `ImageView` is on another `ImageView` and I am using `RelativeLayout` & the Both `ImageView` size is Wrap Content But the problem is if I click on `ImageView2` that time the `Imageview2` is displayed on the `Imageview1` and if I click on `ImageView1` that time the `Imageview1` is displayed on the `Imageview2` I am using bring-to-front method but this is not working. Sorry for bad English Communication. Please Help Me.

Thanks in Advance

Following is My Code.

Main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/mRlayout1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mImageView1" android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/mRlayout2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mImageView2" android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java File:-

```
public class BodyTemp extends Activity {
    ImageView mImageView1, mImageView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView1);
        mImageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mImageView1.bringToFront();
                return true;
            }
        });
        mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView2);
        mImageView2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mImageView2.bringToFront();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate with drawing a picture in mspaint? so we can better understand and solve

Comment: Hello nik, I have edited my question and put the code.

Comment: exactly what you have trying to do? you have not clear that what you want.

Comment: What you trying to do will never work. How can u get a click event on a view that is under another view?

Comment: If i am Click the Imageview2 that time the ImageView1 is go back to ImageView2 and if i am Click on ImageView1 that time the ImageView2 is come to front of the ImageView2.

Comment: You are confused with that explanation. I dint get a word.

Answer (score 4):

You can bring the background view above the clicked view. Bring `mImageView2` to front when you get a click on `mImageView1` and vice versa.

```
 mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView2);
mImageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mImageView2.bringToFront();
            return true;
        }
    });
    mImageView2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mImageView1.bringToFront();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Also change the layout. Put the imageviews into a single relativelayout. Otherwise `bringToFront` will not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mImageView1" android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mImageView2" android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I used this code but this code is not working if u have any other answer or link please give me.

Comment: I think you are very close to it with this code. Give it a try.

Comment: Set onclicklisteners instead of ontouch.

Comment: I tried your code & also setonclicklistner() Method but this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use FrameLayout Instead of RelativeLayout. And Set widht and height of imageview to match_parent. I'm Sure it will work Fine.